# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xarray.core.accessors'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-xarray, metpy

I am new to python, and trying to run Metpy tutorial with xarray, before its ok but after I update xarray to newer version then it show an error

I have tried to create another environment in anaconda prompt, and install every module including metpy (xarray is already included)

```
import metpy
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-4fe739b01247> in <module>
----> 1 import metpy

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\cobaxarray\lib\site-packages\metpy\__init__.py in <module>
     13 
     14 from ._version import get_versions  # noqa: E402
---> 15 from .xarray import *  # noqa: F401, F403
     16 __version__ = get_versions()['version']
     17 del get_versions

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\cobaxarray\lib\site-packages\metpy\xarray.py in <module>
     11 
     12 import xarray as xr
---> 13 from xarray.core.accessors import DatetimeAccessor
     14 from xarray.core.indexing import expanded_indexer
     15 from xarray.core.utils import either_dict_or_kwargs, is_dict_like

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xarray.core.accessors'
```

```
This is the xarray installed versions outside my environment
INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 3.7.3 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Mar 27 2019, 23:18:50) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
python-bits: 64
OS: Windows
OS-release: 8.1
machine: AMD64
processor: Intel64 Family 6 Model 69 Stepping 1, GenuineIntel
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: None
LOCALE: None.None
libhdf5: 1.10.4
libnetcdf: 4.6.2

xarray: 0.12.2
pandas: 0.24.2
numpy: 1.16.3
scipy: 1.2.1
netCDF4: 1.5.1.2
pydap: None
h5netcdf: None
h5py: 2.9.0
Nio: None
zarr: None
cftime: 1.0.3.4
nc_time_axis: 1.1.0
PseudonetCDF: None
rasterio: None
cfgrib: None
iris: None
bottleneck: 1.2.1
dask: 1.2.2
distributed: 1.28.1
matplotlib: 3.1.0
cartopy: 0.17.0
seaborn: 0.9.0
numbagg: None
setuptools: 41.0.1
pip: 19.1.1
conda: 4.7.5
pytest: 4.5.0
IPython: 7.5.0
sphinx: 2.0.1
```

```
This is the installed version of xarray inside my environment
INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 3.7.3 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jul  1 2019, 22:01:29) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
python-bits: 64
OS: Windows
OS-release: 8.1
machine: AMD64
processor: Intel64 Family 6 Model 69 Stepping 1, GenuineIntel
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: None
LOCALE: None.None
libhdf5: None
libnetcdf: None

xarray: 0.12.2
pandas: 0.24.2
numpy: 1.16.4
scipy: 1.2.1
netCDF4: None
pydap: None
h5netcdf: None
h5py: None
Nio: None
zarr: None
cftime: None
nc_time_axis: None
PseudonetCDF: None
rasterio: None
cfgrib: None
iris: None
bottleneck: None
dask: None
distributed: None
matplotlib: 3.1.1
cartopy: 0.17.0
seaborn: None
numbagg: None
setuptools: 41.0.1
pip: 19.1.1
conda: None
pytest: None
IPython: 7.6.1
sphinx: None
```

I want to get the exact result from metpy tutorial, but module not found when importing metpy module create an error that failed the tutorial, thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue is due to Xarray's update to 0.12.2. A new release of MetPy just went out yesterday, so these issues have been resolved. If you just upgrade MetPy, everything should work again: `pip install --upgrade metpy`

Answer (score 0):

Go to `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\cobaxarray\lib\site-packages\metpy\xarray.py`

find the line `from xarray.core.accessors import DatetimeAccessor`

change it to `from xarray.core.accessor_dt import DatetimeAccessor`

Comment: Well, it was because of the version change anyways. No problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had to dereference `anaconda3` in my `.bashrc` file, then reinstall the 2020 version of `anaconda3` and let it initialize itself in `.bashrc`.
Then I did...

```
conda update --all
conda update spyder
```

...then I did these both again to make sure everything got installed.

Then...

```
conda install -c conda-forge metpy
```

It installed a good version of everything (including `xarray`) and now the examples in the MetPy Gallery work as advertised!